# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't load graph

Tags: openstreetmap, graphhopper

I am Working Graphhoper code . I have shape file and Graphhoper work in *.pbf,*.OSM (Open Street Map) . but I have shape file so I am convert shape file to osm file by using Merkaartor but and use in Graphopper but I am Facing following error

```
INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: osm must not be empty. read 96080 lines and 0 locations
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't load graph
    at com.graphhopper.http.DefaultModule.configure(DefaultModule.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:118)
    at com.graphhopper.http.GHServer$1.configure(GHServer.java:117)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.graphhopper.http.GHServer.start(GHServer.java:64)
    at com.graphhopper.http.GHServer.main(GHServer.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: osm must not be empty. read 96080 lines and 0 locations
    at com.graphhopper.reader.OSMReader.writeOsm2Graph(OSMReader.java:329)
    at com.graphhopper.reader.OSMReader.readGraph(OSMReader.java:152)
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.importData(GraphHopper.java:668)
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.process(GraphHopper.java:637)
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.importOrLoad(GraphHopper.java:610)
    at com.graphhopper.http.DefaultModule.createGraphHopper(DefaultModule.java:56)
    at com.graphhopper.http.DefaultModule.configure(DefaultModule.java:69)
    ... 14 more

Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Explicit bindings are required and java.lang.Boolean annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jsonpAllowed) is not explicitly bound.
  while locating java.lang.Boolean annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jsonpAllowed)
    for field at com.graphhopper.http.GHBaseServlet.jsonpAllowed(GHBaseServlet.java:41)
  at com.graphhopper.http.GHServletModule.configureServlets(GHServletModule.java:61)

2) Explicit bindings are required and java.lang.Boolean annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jsonpAllowed) is not explicitly bound.
  while locating java.lang.Boolean annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jsonpAllowed)
    for field at com.graphhopper.http.GHBaseServlet.jsonpAllowed(GHBaseServlet.java:41)
  at com.graphhopper.http.GHServletModule.configureServlets(GHServletModule.java:64)

3) Explicit bindings are required and java.lang.Boolean annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jsonpAllowed) is not explicitly bound.
  while locating java.lang.Boolean annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jsonpAllowed)
    for field at com.graphhopper.http.GHBaseServlet.jsonpAllowed(GHBaseServlet.java:41)
  at com.graphhopper.http.GHServletModule.configureServlets(GHServletModule.java:67)

4) Explicit bindings are required and java.lang.Boolean annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jsonpAllowed) is not explicitly bound.
  while locating java.lang.Boolean annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jsonpAllowed)
    for field at com.graphhopper.http.GHBaseServlet.jsonpAllowed(GHBaseServlet.java:41)
  at com.graphhopper.http.GHServletModule.configureServlets(GHServletModule.java:70)

5) An exception was caught and reported. Message: Couldn't load graph
  at com.graphhopper.http.GHServer$1.configure(GHServer.java:117)

6) Explicit bindings are required and com.graphhopper.GraphHopper is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.graphhopper.GraphHopper
    for field at com.graphhopper.http.GraphHopperServlet.hopper(GraphHopperServlet.java:56)
  at com.graphhopper.http.GHServletModule.configureServlets(GHServletModule.java:67)

7) Explicit bindings are required and com.graphhopper.http.RouteSerializer is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.graphhopper.http.RouteSerializer
    for field at com.graphhopper.http.GraphHopperServlet.routeSerializer(GraphHopperServlet.java:56)
  at com.graphhopper.http.GHServletModule.configureServlets(GHServletModule.java:67)

8) Explicit bindings are required and com.graphhopper.util.TranslationMap is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.graphhopper.util.TranslationMap
    for field at com.graphhopper.http.I18NServlet.map(I18NServlet.java:38)
  at com.graphhopper.http.GHServletModule.configureServlets(GHServletModule.java:61)

9) Explicit bindings are required and com.graphhopper.GraphHopper is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.graphhopper.GraphHopper
    for field at com.graphhopper.http.InfoServlet.hopper(InfoServlet.java:42)
  at com.graphhopper.http.GHServletModule.configureServlets(GHServletModule.java:64)

10) Explicit bindings are required and com.graphhopper.GraphHopper is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.graphhopper.GraphHopper
    for field at com.graphhopper.http.NearestServlet.hopper(NearestServlet.java:40)
  at com.graphhopper.http.GHServletModule.configureServlets(GHServletModule.java:70)

10 errors
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:154)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.graphhopper.http.GHServer.start(GHServer.java:64)
    at com.graphhopper.http.GHServer.main(GHServer.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't load graph
    at com.graphhopper.http.DefaultModule.configure(DefaultModule.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:118)
    at com.graphhopper.http.GHServer$1.configure(GHServer.java:117)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: osm must not be empty. read 96080 lines and 0 locations
    at com.graphhopper.reader.OSMReader.writeOsm2Graph(OSMReader.java:329)
    at com.graphhopper.reader.OSMReader.readGraph(OSMReader.java:152)
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.importData(GraphHopper.java:668)
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.process(GraphHopper.java:637)
    at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.importOrLoad(GraphHopper.java:610)
    at com.graphhopper.http.DefaultModule.createGraphHopper(DefaultModule.java:56)
    at com.graphhopper.http.DefaultModule.configure(DefaultModule.java:69)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Sounds like your input file has the wrong format. Can you compare its content with a regular .osm file that you didn't convert from a shapefile?

Comment: as the exception says 'osm must not be empty. read 96080 lines and 0 locations': GraphHopper will only import if there are ways and all are properly tagged (e.g. with highway) I don't think that the converter knows which highways to choose ...

Comment: The export assumes no highway OSM ways I think. So if you create OSM data out of something else, you'll have to make sure the highway tag is included for the ways you need for GraphHopper.